# How to save a file to a folder in blazor with syncfushion?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, syncfusion

I'm trying to save a file in the "sample/save" using the syncfusion SfUploader I think I'm defining the path wrong.

```
<SfUploader ID="UploadFiles">
   <UploaderEvents></UploaderEvents>
   <UploaderAsyncSettings SaveUrl="sample/save"></UploaderAsyncSettings>
</SfUploader>
```

It gives me this error on the browser console.

> HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
> (XHR)POST - https://localhost:33478/sample/save

(new to blazor)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Suspecting that the controller name and the name in SaveUrl are not identical. Please ensure that the API controller name and SaveUrl name are same. Also refer the below sample and UG.

Sample Link : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Uploader449877060

UG Link     : https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/file-upload/getting-started/#with-server-side-api-endpoint